# "Can't reference system.drawing.dll" in C#

Tags: c#

When I create the code that continuously executes the function, it works normally for 4 minutes, but an error appears:

> Can not reference system.drawing.dll

and it can not be executed.

I've tried searching the web a couple of times to solve it, but I have not had the same experience with you. Try writing a Google translation and ask a question.

```
public static Bitmap GetScreenshot(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(null, hwnd), out rc);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Right - rc.Left, rc.Bottom - rc.Top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    IntPtr hdcBitmap;

    try
    {
        hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

    bool succeeded = PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0x3);
    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);

    if (!succeeded)
    {
        gfxBmp.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
    }

    IntPtr hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hRgn);

    Region region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);//err here once

    if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))
    {
        gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);
        gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    }

    gfxBmp.Dispose();
    return bmp;
}

Timer timer3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer3.Interval = 1; // 1초
timer3.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick2);
timer3.Start();
```

Comment: `but the error "Can not reference system.drawing.dll" appears` Please include a screenshot.

Comment: We don't know what kind of project this is, which makes it much harder to help you.

Comment: So after 4 minutes of running `timer_Tick2` with an interval of 1 ms, after 4*60*1000 = 360k runs you run into trouble. Let's have a look at `timer_Tick2` then!! Also: What do you do with all those bitmaps??

Comment: @TaW it looks like hes monitoring user window, by the high interval, I think he is taking a shot at remote control. to the question, i find it hard to believe Can not reference system.drawing.dll is thrown at runtime

Comment: Well, that is probably why `mjwills` asked for a screenshot 1 hour ago. As it stands the question ought to be closed for more than one reason..

Comment: He is right. I am monitoring the screen and creating the code to run the program according to the results of the analysis of the screen motion. I do not know how to solve this problem.
It seems to cause OutOfMemoryExceptions in GDI +. I tried all the way to kill the Momori leak.
I really appreciate the answer.
GfxBmp.Dispose ();
Region.Dispose ();
Of course I tried this method.
I can not find a solution.
Save me from this repeated hell.

Comment: Exception raised: 'System.ArgumentException' (System.Drawing.dll)
'Color extraction.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Color extraction.vshost.exe): 'C: \ WINDOWS \ Microsoft.Net \ assembly \ GAC_MSIL \ mscorlib.resources \ v4.0_4.0.0.0_ko_b77a5c561934e089 \ mscorlib. Resources.dll 'has been loaded. Modules were built without symbols.

Comment: Exception raised: 'System.NullReferenceException' (color extract .exe)
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is invalid.
   Location: System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn (IntPtr hrgn)
   Location: Color Extraction. HP.PrintWindow (IntPtr hwnd) File D: \ make \ 0 [Find Color] \ 0 Memory \ 816 Resolve Memory Rick HP Classes \ Color Extraction \ HP.cs: Line 330

Comment: Exception raised: 'System.NullReferenceException' (color extract .exe)
Exception raised: 'System.ArgumentException' (System.Drawing.dll)
Exception raised: 'System.NullReferenceException' (color extract .exe)
Exception raised: 'System.NullReferenceException' (color extract .exe)
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Location: Color Extract .HP.Hpbar (String noxplayer) File D: \ make \ 0 [Find Color] \ 0 Memory \ 816 Resolve Memory Rick HP Classes \ Color Extraction \ HP.cs: Line 495

Comment: So none of those exceptions is what you told us in your title??? Also: Do not add relevant information in comments! Instead do edit the question!

Comment: `Save me from this repeated hell` Honestly, we are trying to save you. We have asked you to do a number of things (add screenshots, edit the question rather than add comments etc) and you haven't done them. If you provide the information we ask you for, it helps us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably have a memory leak.  Looking through, the thing that I noted was that the [Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region(v=vs.110).aspx) object is not being disposed:

```
Region region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);//err here once
if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))
{
    gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);
    gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
}
gfxBmp.Dispose();
region.Dispose();  //Try adding this in.
return bmp;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. The OP is facing a build-time error - you're talking about a problem that would only manifest at execution time. Sure, it's a problem, and probably worth a comment, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: He said it runs for 4 minutes before he sees the error. Well, that's what I interpreted his problem to be.  Sounded like a memory leak.

Comment: Ah, you're right. That's extremely odd - more detail required. That doesn't sound like the error you'd get from a memory leak though.

Answer (score -1):

```
        IntPtr hRgn = NativeMethod.CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);

        NativeMethod.GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hRgn);

        using (var region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn))
        {
            if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))
            {
                gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);
                gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            }
        }

        gfxBmp.Dispose();

        NativeMethod.DeleteObject(hRgn);
```

It's My Code...

maybe because GDI handle memory leak.

Comment: Can you give more details on your error (call stack). Why do you suspect a memory leak? Did you try to solve it?